# Connecting Facebook account to Concept N

Tags: sony-future-lab-n

I have linked my facebook account on Concept N to the website and on the app, but I can’t see my segment. Can someone help me to troubleshoot this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try unlinking your Facebook account on the website and on the Concept N app. This should help reset things and show you your segments on the Concept N app again.

Also be sure that you are only using one facebook account per Concept N sign up. For instance if you were testing N and signed up with multiple log in accounts, but used the same facebook account it could cause problems.